# How to run only one instance of cordova inappbrowser in android

Tags: android, cordova, inappbrowser

- I have a link that opens in the `inappbrowser` and when I proceed with the webpage that is loaded in the `inappbrowser` , any other link should not get opened if one link is already running in `inappbrowser`.
- Whereas when I click other link, it loads over the previous running link and I clearly do not want that

Any help is much appreciated!

Here is the source code:

```
universalLinks.subscribe(null, function (eventData) {
ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(eventData.url, '_blank', 'location=yes');

setTimeout(function () {
   ref.close();
}, 320000);

});
```

Comment: Can you provide some source code? Please edit your question and add it, and do not post it as a comment to your own question.

Comment: Again, please edit your question and add it, and do NOT post it as a comment to your own question. See these links to understand how StackOverflow works: [HOW TO ASK](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @sɐunıɔןɐqɐp do you have any suggestions??